# how to use aws cloud9 environment id to open an environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I have been getting an Id from the aws CLI but I'm not getting the way of opening the environment without opening the aws console, is there any way of opening it without opening the console?

Answer (score 0):

To open the environment, you must use the AWS Cloud9 console (which is part of the AWS Management Console).

Paul (AWS Cloud9 Documentation)